# Is it possible to use psycopg2 for prepared statements?

Tags: python, postgresql, questdb

I'm comparing some of the features of Postgres clients for compatibility and I'm having difficulty getting prepared statements to work in psychopg2. The Node.js `pg` package allows me to do the following where providing a name (`insert-values`) prepares the query server-side:

```js
    for (let rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {
      // Providing a 'name' field allows for prepared statements / bind variables
      const query = {
        name: "insert-values",
        text: "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);",
        values: [Date.now() * 1000, Date.now(), "node pg prep statement", rows],
      }
      const preparedStatement = await client.query(query)
    }
```

In Python, I'm doing something like this using [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/):

```py
    # insert 10 records
    for x in range(10):
      now = dt.datetime.utcnow()
      date = dt.datetime.now().date()
      cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO trades
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);
        """, (now, date, "python example", x))
    # commit records
    connection.commit()
```

Is there any way to create prepared statements in Python?

**edit** I'm using the samples from [QuestDB documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#postgres-compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No prepared statement support in Psycopg2 even in 2021. Yes you can do PREPARE and use named query with parameters but there is no support from Psycopg2 in the same way as you can find it with Java JDBC or Rust Postgres drivers.

If you start writing loops with INSERT statements the full statement text will be sent every iteration and has to be parsed by the DB so will be measurable IO/CPU an overhead for big loops.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no support for "magically" preparing statements. However, you can execute SQL `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements with `execute()`.

You probably want to read the section on [fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) in the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try `cursor.execute_values()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not?:

```
date = dt.datetime.now().date()
insert_sql = """INSERT INTO trades
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
# insert 10 records
for x in range(10):
    now = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    cursor.execute(insert_sql, (now, date, "python example", x))
# commit records
connection.commit()
```

It works out to the same thing. The query is built once and then it is run multiple times with different parameter for `x`. As @Ture Pålsson pointed out you can combine the `INSERTs` using the helpers here [Fast Execution](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea, but the timestamp will not be updated in the for loop. It looks like I'm still missing something for the statement to be compiled server-side which is possible in node's `pg` library by using a 'name' property.

Comment: Moved the timestamp into the loop. As @TurePålsson suggested you can use `PREPARE/EXECUTE` directly with `cur.execute()`.